# How can I keep XCOM 2 loading in the background?

Tags: macos, xcom-2

I have XCOM 2 open in windowed mode. On loading screens (they're very long) or dialog sequences I would like to tab out to do other things, like read my emails. Yet I don't think XCOM 2 is working while I'm tabbed out. The animations are all paused. The mission briefing dialog is paused. When I put the attention back on the XCOM2 window it resumes.

How do I make sure it's still running even if I'm not on the window?

Comment: Have you tried timing the loading screens?

Comment: For what it's worth, particularly on the returning-to-base load screen, you can press capslock to skip the load screen after a brief hitch (yes, I am not kidding).

Comment: I don't run in windowed mode (at least I dont' think so - I haven't changed from default) but I find that if I tab out to read email and such like then often when I come back it will be giving me the press button to continue suggesting it finished loading while not having focus. Might be different if running full screen than windowed. It may also be that mission briefing pausing doesn't mean loading is paused so worth running some experiments (eg tab out and leave it for 10 minutes or more and see if it does in fact finish).

Comment: When returning from a mission, try pressing "capslock". It'll stop rendering the skyranger and focus entirely on loading the geoscape / avenger. Takes me down from ~40 seconds to ~5.

Comment: @SableDreamer Yes it does work! Thanks that's amusing. Sadly it doesn't work for going to the mission. Maybe it's because it's doing some random generation of the map and that takes a long time?

Comment: @Chris Yes I went to lunch with it loading the background. 30 minutes later it's still loading.

Comment: @Harry I think there's some setting to default the process priority lower if it doesn't have focus. Perhaps you could try increasing that?

Comment: It loads in the background just fine for me, I do it all the time.  Running Windows 7 x64

Comment: Not exactly what we are looking for, but I've noticed that the mission continues to load If i tab out (or move mouse out of game) before the loading screen shows up, doesn't work during mission, but at least you can do stuff while the mission loads.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this yet for XCOM 2 but I did this in Xcom EU by modifying the **baseengine.ini** file:

**bPauseOnLossOfFocus=FALSE**

This file is a standard Unreal Engine file so it should be there for Xcom 2 as well.

Look in: **XCOM 2 installation folder/engine/config**.

Will double check this when I get home.

Comment: It is there in XCOM 2, but it's actually already set to false. Doesn't seem to be having any impact for me though.

Comment: @ChrisHayes  Hmm, thanks Chris, I will have a look